# How do I test my team site before I share it?

Tags: testing

I might not be asking this correctly as I am still very new at SharePoint. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to view my team site as if I was a visitor? This way I can see exactly what they do? Also, I would be able to test all links etc. Am I completely missing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in feature which would allow you to do so. For a developer, tester or an administrator it should be quite ideal to have a separate test account for purposes like this. Then it's only a matter of assigning the corresponding permission for this user.

Comment: Sorry, I sent my message before I was done. I will contact our corporate folks and see if they will provision a test account for me. Again, thank you